# Are the close categories 'too broad' & 'unclear' distinctive enough to be useful?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

While I realize there are some examples when it may be obvious that one of the categories applies, in many cases a bad question could fit both categories. In most of these cases, the question is usually quite short and devoid of any code that exemplifies the issue the poster is having.

For reference, here are the current descriptions of both:

[image]

Specifically, the wording asking for the poster of the question to:

> clarify your specific problem or add additional details

or to:

> edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail

make very similar requests. So similar that I question whether the two categories are useful for the original poster or just cognitive dissonance for the users voting to close the question?

By being closed by either category, the original poster is already aware that there is something wrong with the question, and being asked to clarify it is true for both categories.

Why is this a problem? Because, if even a small number of users get to the pop-up window with these options and then decide to close the window because they don't want to be bothered to decide between these categories, then a bad question has more opportunity to survive. I know I have done this before and I doubt I am the only one.

Comment: I'd say the requests aren't all that similar. The key word in the "too broad" one is "limit" -- what is essential in that case is narrowing the scope of the question to a sufficient degree.

Comment: Right, in both cases, narrowing the scope is needed, thus the question of whether having the categories separated is useful for the original poster vs the simplification of combining the categories for more efficient closing of bad questions.

Comment: @Fiver: Unclear also includes questions which are essentially gibberish. Where what they've asked for either is not a thing or represents such a profound misunderstanding that you need clarification as to what they're even talking about.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I agree. Still, the question is whether the distinction makes a difference for such a user posting that type of question. A request for clarification after closing the question seems sufficient for both cases.

Comment: @Fiver It does make a difference. For a loose analogy, "unclear what you are asking" is "Sorry, but I didn't quite get what you meant", while "too broad" is "Okay, let's take it one step at a time".

Comment: So if you want to have one close reason to cover both, what would the close reason and it's description be?

Comment: @Servy Keeping "unclear" seems a good option, as a question that is too broad is also somewhat unclear in the context of programming. I would just add to the description of the unclear category.

Comment: @Fiver Someone asking, "how do I program in C++" is going to say that their question is *very* clear, and they'd be right.  You *do* know what they're asking, it's just that actually providing an answer to that question is well beyond what can reasonably be answered in the scope of an SO question.  Too Broad explains what's *actually* wrong with a question like that, and Unclear doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

They're two sides of the same coin: a question that isn't fully specified. Unclear leaves out which information is needed, while Too Broad leaves out which information is *important.*

I'd elaborate... But [jmac already put together this fantastic puzzle analogy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason/215220#215220), so just go read that.

Comment: Sure, I get that. The issue isn't whether there is a difference between left out information that is needed vs important, rather whether the distinction is useful for the original poster to clarify the question vs the overlap of the two that creates a potential barrier towards closing the question.

Comment: Five votes closes no matter the reason. If someone can't decide and chooses none, maybe there wasn't a problem to begin with. I'd have to see more than speculation here I'm afraid.

Comment: Maybe, but that is the discussion I was hoping to have here. I would say that if someone's immediate reaction to a question is that it is terrible, and clicks to close it, then can't decide on the category, it says more about the close options than the question's content.

Comment: Tons of people do that all the time, @Fiver. That's why we have to be very, very careful about which reasons are in the list. If we deviate from "will cause harm" into "annoys some non-trivial minority", a bunch of stuff gets closed that doesn't need to be. We... May've done this a few times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel we would gain much by merging "unclear" and "too broad". I believe they are quite distinct, even on an intuitive level. While "unclear what you are asking" roughly amounts to "sorry, but I didn't quite get what you meant", "too broad" is more like "okay, let's take it one step at a time". From an answer writing perspective, we might say that an "unclear" question can't be given a proper answer because we can't tell what an answer should address, while a "too broad" question *could* be given a proper answer, but it would be too unwieldy for this site (because it would e.g. involve writing a full blown language basics tutorial, or squeezing five answers into a single post, or writing the asker's entire end-of-term project).

Merging "unclear" and "too broad" would result in a rather vague close reason. The automatic explanation given by the system to the asker would become less clear, and having fewer reference points might also make writing custom explanations trickier. Furthermore, vagueness is likely to lead to increased misuse of close votes, by encouraging ad hoc interpretations and imprecise justifications. That would go counter to the moves towards sharper close reasons over the years.

Personally, I use "too broad" significantly more often than "unclear", and I hardly ever find myself having trouble to decide which of them should be applied on a question. Your mileage might vary -- perhaps there are different scenarios to be found across the various tags -- but I don't think merging them would make content curation an easier task for me.

(P.S.: This late answer was motivated by the merger suggestion having resurfaced [in a different context](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368924/2751851).)

Comment: Thanks for adding some thoughts. I think the intent of my question was missed somewhat by most of the comments (perhaps I didn't explain it well).  It was meant to be more of whether it is actually useful to the original poster. In other words, how many questions put on hold because of these 2 reasons are actually edited and saved? At the same time, these two categories are nearly the only ones I see with split votes when I vote to close a bad question. So another stat that would be interesting to see is the percentage of closed questions with split votes by close category.

Comment: [1/2] @Fiver Here are some stats for the past 30 days, taken from the 10k tools: 5059 questions were closed as "too broad" (18.16% of closures), and 3541 as "unclear" (12.71%). 20.62% of the "too broad" questions were edited, and 1.19% ones were reopened; among the edited ones, the reopen rate was 4.03%. For "unclear", the ratios were, respectively, 26.21% (highest among all close reasons), 2.57% (third highest) and 7.22% (second highest). The reasons with higher salvage than "unclear" rates are "duplicate" (22.26%, 3.66%, 3.96%) and "off-topic/MCVE" (20.92%, 2.91%, 11.35%).

Comment: [2/2] @Fiver Off-topic closures other than "off-topic/MCVE" have low salvage rates, presumably because it is hard to rescue a question whose subject matter is outside of the scope of the site. Besides that, there seems to be a pattern of sharper, more actionable close reasons having higher salvage rates. I feel that lends some support to my conjecture that merging "too broad" (which already is a rather broad reason to begin with) and "unclear" would make salvaging harder, though it remains just a conjecture.