# Should we rethink flags?

Tags: feature-request, flags

Our current set of flags for questions is as follows:

[image]
[image]

And I am often confused as to which one to use.

For example a post provides no code and asks for us to write it for them. Do you flag as **'off-topic -> asking for debugging help'**, **'unclear'** or **'too broad'**?

It is not just this, I find this often.

I think it should be made more obvious which flag to use in most cases, either by removing/adding flags, or just changing the description, or both.

Comment: I agree with the issue of selecting **unclear** or **too broad** - It always seems to be a toss up between those two.

Comment: Suggested edits review responses are not flags. Your are mixing up two different things.

Comment: closely related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368924/how-can-we-streamline-the-close-flagging-and-voting-dialogues

Comment: *For example a post provides no code and asks for us to write it for them.* There is no close reason for this. Questions like this might often be too broad or unclear but we don't close questions just because someone's asking for code.

Comment: @dwirony If it's a toss-up, it's usually because it actually *is* both unclear and too broad (e.g. with zero-effort requirements dumps) - in that case, you can just pick whichever one you prefer.

Comment: @EJoshuaS there's nothing precluding a "zero-effort requirement dump" from being a reasonably scoped and well defined on-topic programming question, so long as the requirement is reasonably scoped and well defined. It is when such questions are not reasonably scoped (too broad) or well defined (unclear) that they become too broad and / or unclear respectively.

Comment: @TinyGiant They could also be off-topic if they're homework questions.

Comment: @EJoshuaS there's nothing precluding a "homework question" from being a reasonably scoped and well defined on-topic programming question, so long as the "homework question" is reasonably scoped and well defined. It is when such questions are not reasonably scoped (too broad) or well defined (unclear) that they become too broad and / or unclear respectively.

Comment: The point is that we don't have a "zero-effort requirement dump" close reason or a "homework question" close reason. [If you need to bend a close reason to fit the question in order to justify closure, the closure isn't really justified.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846). Saying things like "All (zero-effort requirement dumps / homework questions) should be closed as (too broad / unclear)" is just not true, even if there is some tendency in that direction. Questions that are too broad should be closed as too broad, and questions that are unclear should be closed as unclear, plain and simple.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Maybe* some wordsmithing is warranted, but I don't normally find an issue.

To use your example:

- When they're asking us to write code for them, that sounds like a lot of work and the scope of success is broad at best, so I close as "Too Broad".
- When they have a problem and a stack trace but no code to follow the stack trace, then they have a debugging question and there should be code, so I flag to close for that reason.
- If I can't make heads of tails of what it is they're talking about, then I flag to close as "Unclear".

The same is true of edits.  I use "no improvement whatsoever" as an objective neutral party coming into the question.  If I don't feel like the question reads better or is made clearer with the improvements that were made, then I usually reject with that reason.  If it seems like their edit was putting words in the author's mouth, I usually go wth "clearly conflicts with author's intent".

Comment: My problem is that if I don't know which flag to use, other new users likely won't either, possibly causing question dupes on meta, and a lot of confusion. The flag summery is there for a reason; to explain when the flag should be used, and I don't think it is obvious enough.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think the reasons need to be changed because the reasons themselves are clear and distinct. They apply to distinct problems, though any single post may suffer from multiple problems.

---

#### The "Debugging / No MCVE" close reason

This reason **only** applies to questions asking us to debug code that the author has written. This is for questions that either:

- do not include enough code to reproduce the problem,
- include too much code to for us to reasonably be expected to comb through in order to narrow down the source of the problem,
- want us to debug a problem on a live website,
- want us to go somewhere to download / get the code,
- or they just plain old forgot to include the code.

Or, in short:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

#### Questions asking how to accomplish a task

These questions are not inherently off-topic, but must be **reasonably scoped** and **well defined**:

- **reasonably scoped**, meaning that they can only ask how to do one thing, not seven things wrapped up in one problem.

  > Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.
- **well defined**, meaning the thing being asked for must be clear and unambiguous.

  > Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

These questions do not require code, though code (even pseudo code) can sometimes help with defining or narrowing down the problem. See: [What's better: a question with no attempt or with an unfixable/irrelevant attempt?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338846/4639281)

Also related: [Do we need a close reason for zero-effort questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260909/4639281)

Answer (score 3):

`tl;dr:`

> Are we going to overhaul it? Maybe .. probably .. a little? What's becoming increasingly clear is our lack of *breadth* in UX research is a pain point, especially on stuff that was bolted together on top of stuff that got bolted together over the years. But we can't do anything until we get better at research, and fortunately we now have that kind of talent at the company and actively working on it. But saying "This feels weird to use" is good signal to help guide those efforts.

From a UX perspective, the flag dialogs are a mess. Now, admitting that doesn't automatically preclude them from working for the majority of touches and uses, it just admits that they just feel *off*, even though attempts at describing what could be improved fail to allude to more than a trivial amount of net benefit.

That's sometimes a symptom of just trying to accomplish too many things in a single interface, so yeah, we should be thinking about that. We should *always* be thinking about that, because it's a pretty critical part of the system that can have a pretty strong influence over how folks experience the site.

I think we're going to need to eventually break duplication out into its own workflow, as having that opens up some more possibilities for much needed attention in that department. I also think we should be treating spam and abuse separately, and more.

The problem (and part of the reason why you might see some disagreement with the proposal) is, *it makes pretty clear sense to almost everyone that's going to read this*, mostly because quite a few of us were around to watch it evolve from a terse, humble single modal dialog. Getting more outsider perspectives and data (as in "please read this list of options and tell us what you understand them to mean" is something we're getting better at doing, some of the user interviews we have are *beyond* enlightening, stuff you'd never think was ambiguous can be broadly misunderstood. We're ramping this research up as we dive deeper into exclusion analysis; it's a pretty deep rabbit hole.

So, in a technical sense, I agree that we should consistently think about ways to improve (and possibly break up) much of the functionality there - as in we should always be doing research and looking for opportunities. But we definitely can't overhaul it without pretty clear goals that can be tested, and a plan.

But in a broader sense, what we're essentially saying here is that we should agree that we'll eventually agree on some improvements, and we've had *lots* of discussions about it which many here stilll easily recall, so that outside perspective is pretty critical since we're becoming a bit of an echo chamber when it comes to making strides there.

We'll share what we learn, and then we can (together) try to bridge the dissonance between what we want to say in UX writing, and what people not actively involved in vetting features actually understand.

Someone pointed out to me just recently that if we were a car company, we'd *occasionally* forget to ship right-side drive models, just because our testing and research has (historically) been quite limited. I chuckled heavily as I read that, because it's even more funny when it's true :)

So while even I'd disagree on the extent that it's a mess, and I know the people that touch it the most have a good grasp on what everything was intended to do, I can't help but acknowledge how confusing it is to folks that weren't so tied to how it became what it did.